# Hide div if it doesn't have class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a portfolio with different tags like *code* & *design* - then I want a nav at the top that when you click on the word code - it will hide all divs except for those with a class name code. And vice versa for design.

I've seen a few examples for things using the .not jQuery function, but I can't get it working with mine

```
<a id="code-btn" href="#"> Show Code </a>
<a id="design-btn" href="#"> Show Design </a>

<div class="box d">test</div>
<div class="box c">test</div>
<div class="box d">test</div>

<script>
    $("#code-btn").click(function() {
        $('div').not('.' + c).hide();
    });
</script>
```

I don't want to use a toggle, as I may add more tags later, like logo etc.

Comment: `'.c'` and not `'.' + c` as you don't have any variable `c`. I'll suggest `$('div.box:not(.c)')`

Comment: Why are you doing this backwards? Simply hide the `d`s: `$('.d').hide();`

Comment: Wouldn't `$('.d').hide();` work?

Comment: OP might have other class and only needs to show div of a specific class. so using not would be the best option instead of hiding all one by one

Comment: @Tushar I got it working with $("#code-btn").click(function() {
$('div.box').not('.c').hide()
});

Thanks!!!

Comment: And... you actually don't need js for this at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Concatination with class...

Checkout This... This Might Be Helpful...

```js
$("#code-btn").click(function() {
        $('div').not('.c').hide();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="code-btn" href="#"> Show Code </a>
<a id="design-btn" href="#"> Show Design </a>

<div class="box d">test d</div>
<div class="box c">test c</div>
<div class="box a">test a</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try smth. like this: 
`$("div").filter(":not('.c')").hide();`

Comment: .c needs to be in double quotes.

Comment: Now, .c needs to be in single quotes.

Comment: No need for quotes inside :not() selector. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp

Comment: W3Schools should be taken with a grain of salt. How would :not(.a .b) work out?

Answer (score 0):

Here - done with just CSS, no JS needed at all.

```css
.button {
  margin: 0 2em;
  }

div {
  display: none;
  }
div:target {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<a class="button" id="code-btn" href="#code"> Show Code </a>
<a class="button" id="design-btn" href="#design"> Show Design </a>

<div id="code">Code</div>
<div id="design">Design</div>
```

Comment: Caveat: single container and fixed order (as in cannot have `box c + box d + box c`)

Comment: True, but in this particular case, why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

my version which uses one event handler for both

```
       $("a").click(function (evt) {
                var showCode = this.id == "code-btn";
                $("div.c").toggle(showCode);
                $("div.d").toggle(!showCode);
            }
                )
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need please check the below snippet

```js
$(function(){
$('#code-btn').on('click', function(){
 if($('.box').hasClass('c')){
  $('.c').css('display','block'); 
  $('.d').css('display','none');
 }
});
$('#design-btn').on('click', function(){
 if($('.box').hasClass('d')){
  $('.d').css('display','block'); 
  $('.c').css('display','none');
 }
});
});
```

```css
.box {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<a id="code-btn" href="#"> Show Code </a>
<a id="design-btn" href="#"> Show Design </a>

<div class="box d">design</div>
<div class="box c">code</div>
<div class="box d">design</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```